# Hosting ASP.NET Core as Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core, .net-core

As I get it in RC2 there's a support for hosting applications within Windows Services. I tried to test it on a simple web api project (using .NET Framework 4.6.1).

Here's my Program.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;

namespace WebApplication4
{
  public class Program : ServiceBase
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      if (args.Contains("--windows-service"))
      {
        Run(new Program());
        return;
      }

      var program = new Program();
      program.OnStart(null);
      Console.ReadLine();
      program.OnStop();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())      
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .Build();

      host.RunAsService();
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {}
  }
}
```

All the other stuff are basically from .NET Core template (though I changed framework to net461 and added some dependencies in project.json).

After publishing it with `dotnet publish` and creating Windows Service with `sc create` I can succesfully start my service, but I can't reach any of my controllers (ports are not listeting). I assume I'm doing something wrong.

So I guess the main question is how to make self hosted web api and run it as Windows Service. All found solutions don't work after RC2 update.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's going on, but your code works fine for when I run it as a Windows service, as long as I *don't* pass `--windows-service` to it.

Comment: Actually the ASP.NET team already provides that class. There is even a NuGet for it. Just try it, but does not seem to be easy as well: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1386

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When run from the command line (i.e. without --windows-service) it works fine. Creating the service works fine (e.g. "sc.exe ABC -binPath= "<path to exe> --window-service") and starting the service from Services is fine and shows that it's Running but trying to access the service via http://localhost:5000 doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, how where you able to add a reference to System.ServiceProcess? I cannot add the reference to my netcoreapp1.0 targeted project

Comment: @LuisBecerril `System.ServiceProcess` is not available in `netcoreapp1.0` (CoreCLR) yet. As mentioned, you'll have to target full framework, e.g. `net461` and then reference `frameworkAssemblies`.

Comment: Were you able to make this work @maria-p?

Answer (score 56):

You've got a couple of options here - use Microsoft's WebHostService class, inherit WebHostService or write your own. The reason for the latter being that using Microsoft's implementation, we cannot write a generic extension method with a type parameter inheriting WebHostService since this class does not contain a parameterless constructor nor can we access the service locator.

### Using WebHostService

In this example, I'm going to create a Console Application that uses Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets, outputs an .exe and operates as a MVC app (Views, Controllers, etc). I assume that creating the Console Application, changing the targets in the .xproj and modifying the project.json to have proper publish options and copying the Views, Controllers and webroot from the standard .NET Core web app template - is trivial.

Now the essential part:

1. Get [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices) package and make sure your framework in project.json file is net451 (or newer)
2. Make sure the content root in the entry point is properly set to the publish directory of the application .exe file and that the RunAsService() extension method is called. E.g:

   ```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var exePath= System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
       var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);

       var host = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(directoryPath)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();

       if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
       {
           host.Run();
       }
       else
       {
           host.RunAsService();
       }
   }
   ```

The .exe can now easily be installed using the following command

```
    sc create MyService binPath = "Full\Path\To\The\Console\file.exe"
```

Once the service is started, the web application is hosted and successfully finds and renders its Views.

### Inherit WebHostService

One major benefit of this approach is that this lets us override the OnStopping, OnStarting and OnStarted methods.

Let's assume that the following is our custom class that inherits WebHostService

```
internal class CustomWebHostService : WebHostService
{
    public CustomWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStarting(string[] args)
    {
        // Log
        base.OnStarting(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        // More log
        base.OnStarted();
    }

    protected override void OnStopping()
    {
        // Even more log
        base.OnStopping();
    }
}
```

Following the steps above, we have to write down our own extension method that runs the host using our custom class:

```
public static class CustomWebHostWindowsServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsCustomService(this IWebHost host)
    {
        var webHostService = new CustomWebHostService(host);
        ServiceBase.Run(webHostService);
    }
}
```

The only line that remains to be changed from the previous example of the entry point is the else statement in the end, it has to call the proper extension method

```
host.RunAsCustomService();
```

Finally, installing the service using the same steps as above.

```
sc create MyService binPath = "Full\Path\To\The\Console\file.exe"
```

Comment: Full sample is available here. https://github.com/lankaapura/MusicStoreAsWindowsService

Comment: @Ivan Prodanov Do you know if it's possible to get this running on Linux?

Comment: @JosephWoodward I'm quite certain this won't work on Linux in its current form.

Comment: `.UseContentRoot(directoryPath)` should be `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` if wwwroot is needed

Comment: @nadav GetCurrentDirectory() will return %WinDir%\System32 (or %winDir%\SysWoW64 if x64) when started from the service control manager.

Comment: This is the only way i could define the WWWROOT to be the starting point of my app

Comment: any changes for dotnet core 2.0?

Comment: @aleha this solution works for dotnet core 2.1, but not for earlier versions

Comment: `binpath` cannot have spaces around the `=`. It is also documented as without the capitalization, but that isn't required.

Comment: Is there a way to override OnStopping/OnStarting when using host.Run() to allow debug directly when starting code from VS, not just by running code as windows service and attaching debugger to it? 

Right now I can debug everything  from VS but OnStopping/OnStarging is not called for obvious reason.

Answer (score 10):

If it is okay to run on full .NET Framework only, the previous answers are sufficient (Inheriting from `ServiceBase` or using Microsoft's `WebHostService`).

If, however, you have / want to run on **.NET Core only** (e.g. on windows nano server, single binary that works on linux as normal app and as service on windows, or need to run side-by-side with apps on an old .NET Framework version so you can't  update the system framework), you'd have to make the appropriate windows API calls yourself via P/Invokes. Since i had to do that, i created a [library that does exactly that](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service).

There is a [sample](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service/blob/2c52baf16006f34bfeb2e6954cb7a376c231bc60/samples/TestService/Program.cs) available that is also able to install itself when run with administrative privileges (e.g. `dotnet MyService.dll --register-as-service`).

Comment: Does it support .net core 2.0?

Comment: @Isantipov look at the github link he provided:
...
Prerequisites:

.NET Core SDK 2.0.3 or higher (.csproj based tooling)

Answer (score 7):

You need to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices` and use this code in your Startup class to make it runnable as a windows service:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(@"Path\To\Content\Root")
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

    if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
    {
        host.Run();
    }
    else
    {
        host.RunAsService();
    }
}
```

Then you need to add an extension method for `IWebHost.RunAsService` to wrap it with your custom `WebHostService` class with `OnStopping` and `OnStarting` event handlers:

```
public static class MyWebHostServiceServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsMyService(this IWebHost host)
    {
        var webHostService = new MyWebHostService(host);
        ServiceBase.Run(webHostService);
    }
}

internal class MyWebHostService : WebHostService
{
    public MyWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStarting(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStarting(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        base.OnStarted();
    }

    protected override void OnStopping()
    {
        base.OnStopping();
    }
}
```

This post [How to host your ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-host-your-aspnet-core-in-a-windows-service/) and comments cover the details.

**UPDATE** (see more details in [Quick summary of what’s new in ASP.NET Core 2.0](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-asp-net-core-2-0/)):

In `ASP.NET Core 1.1` we had something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

In `ASP.NET Core 2.0`, it looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Looking at your update, with the changes from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0, does this mean that if my environment is 2.0, I should "upgrade" my code or will the 1.1 version still work?

Comment: @WouterVanherck you could always check what it does https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0-preview1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs

Comment: @DmitryPavlov - i got error "can not resolve symbol `WebHost`" in .Net Core 2.0. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: In .NET Core 3: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services

Comment: Good example, but I think you may want to change the line host.RunAsService(); to host.RunAsMyService(); so it matches the extender

Answer (score 2):

I found this topic while looking for a solution to a similar problem. Ended up implementing something that works pretty much like very (very) simplified Topshelf. You can easily run as console and/or install, uninstall and so one as a service. I think it can be pretty useful for somebody. You can find the code here : https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService and there's nuget here as well https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService/ . Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Services can be easily created with Visual Studio 2017. You will need to move your .NET Core code to a class library that targets NetStandard that can then be referenced. Your Windows Service project will have to target the full .NET Framework but can reference your shared library.

By putting all of your code in the class library you would then have portability between the Windows Service and other non Windows apps.

With VS 2015 you couldn't make a Windows Service project and reference a .NET Core xproj. Visual Studio 2017 fixes that once you convert all your projects to csproj.

This blog walks through it in more detail: [How to Create .NET Core Windows Services With Visual Studio 2017](https://stackify.com/creating-net-core-windows-services/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest VS2015 Update 2 ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template and with the mods to Program.cs as below, it is working just fine when run as a service, stand-alone and in VS. Notice that the path to the directory containing wwwroot needs to be set when run as a service.

So far, I really like this template and pattern. Can develop MVC6 code as usual in Visual Studio and then it deploys cleanly as a service. In fact, I noticed that when deploying a local instance of the service for testing that there is no need to delete/create service using sc.exe. Just stop the service, publish the code and restart the service and it'll pick up the new changes.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        if (args.Contains("--windows-service"))
        {
            host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot("<directory-containing-wwwroot>")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://+:5000")
            .Build();

            Startup.is_service = true;
            host.RunAsService();
        }
        else
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the OS add the "--windows-service" command line argument when it launches the service?

Comment: sc.exe <service-name> binPath= "<service-exe-path> --windows-service". thus supply the --windows-service as part of the binPath

Comment: "Startup.is_service = true;" does not seem to work in my rc2 template. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: @JDTLH9 I'm assuming this is a custom property

Comment: I don't have `RunAsService` on `IWebHost` - where is this coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Updated for what I Use for .netcore 2.1, using as much of the stock template as possible, which includes reading configuration from the appsettings.json, command args, host filtering etc, as implemented inside the helper methods from the .netcore team. A lot of these settings are thus controlled via config files or command args. check microsoft's documentation on what he stock template provides and how to override settings.

Please note that I have seen the service fail to start if you define an endpoint with https and the default development certificate. It may simply be a matter of specifying a pfx via configuration. If anybody wants to improve upon this, feel free to do so.

anyway here is the stock template code I use in program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Contains("--service"))
        {
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path); // need this because WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder queries current directory to look for config files and content root folder. service start up sets this to win32's folder.
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.RunAsService();
        }
        else
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```