# Is it possible to run a .NET Core console application silently (hide console window)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to automate some tasks for myself and I wrote a few .NET Core 1.0 console applications. One of them is BrowserRouter - a simple application which, based on a URL pattern, decides which browser / browser profile to open when I click on HTTP(S) links.

That works fine, but there is always the console window which appears and immediately disappears.

Is there a way to run the .NET Core console application silently (hiding the console window)?

I know in the full .NET Framework it is possible to change the output type to *Windows Application*, but that's not available (yet?) for .NET Core.

Comment: What about using a windows service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Run a C# console application with the console hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

Comment: @VahidNaderi .Net Core is X-Plat - not sure how a Windows Service would work on Linux/MAC.

Comment: @DaveShaw you're right, then maybe we should [vote for it](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9515328-windows-services-in-net-core)

Comment: @mThurston No, the other question is 1. not about .net core and 2. addresses the situation when you open a console application from within windows application. So you can control it from within the windows app.

Comment: I think the question is still valid: you may want to build a .net core application (let's assume you are using VSCode rather than VS) and want to launch a windows service (on a window platform, of course).

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346383/hosting-asp-net-core-as-windows-service)

Comment: This answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/836436/453798 might help...

Comment: How do you start BrowserRouter today ?

Answer (score 43):

**Update 2018**: In .NET Core 3.0+, you will be able to set `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` inside of the csproj file.

Currently, this is not *directly* possible out of the box because Windows EXE files contain a flag indicating if it is a "console" or "GUI" application that Windows evaluates even before starting the application. However, this flag can be changed using `editbin.exe` (ships with Visual Studio' C++ build tools as far as I know).

Building on this, you could create a self-contained .NET Core application (removing the `"type": "platform"` from the `project.json` and adding a runtimes section) so your project output includes an actual `.exe` file and add a post-build script that invokes `editbin.exe /subsystem:windows yourapp.exe`.

Comment: There is more documentation for the SUBSYSTEM option for editbin.exe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem

I copied editbin.exe and link.exe to a folder under my solution.  In VS2017 I used the following in the post build event for my project:

`"$(SolutionDir)Build\bin\editbin.exe" -SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "$(SolutionDir)Project1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\Project1.exe"`

I don't know if anyone else has had this, but I couldn't get many of the macros to work (possibly because I had to tweak the csproj to get it to build as an exe).

Comment: @martinullrich 3.0 solution worked great , any idea how I can stop this application after hiding its kestrel cmd . I want to close/stop the application using a button, or icon in windows. any hints?

Comment: In combination with Blazor Server I ran into an issue where Controllers added to a Razor library did not work anymore (missing endpoint).

Answer (score 12):

With .NET Core 3.0+ (including .NET 5), just do this in csproj:

`<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`

Answer (score 6):

I really wanted to do it as Martin resolved, but I couldn't find editbin.exe. Well, I should have run the Visual Studio installer and installed Microsoft Visual C++, but I had limited memory, so I found another way of doing it NSubsys on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubsys).

The application will be made to run in hidden mode on publishing.

Note to copy the Npm install command from NuGet since searching it from package manager for solution didn't seem to find any results.

Comment: Would you be able to provide instructions for how exactly you used NSubsys to get this to work? After installing the NuGet package, what other steps did you have to take? Thanks.

Comment: Also, am I correct in saying that NSubsys won't be triggered on local dev? Will it only be triggered once the program has been published (as a self-contained package)?

Answer (score 4):

In the .NET Core SDK 2.1 (I have 2.1.500) this project file is working:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: But that's not a .Net Core application.

Comment: <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType> is the relevant part here; use <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> for .NETCore 3.1

Comment: @svick: What is it then?

Comment: @PeterMortensen `<TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>` means that it's a .Net Framework 4.7 application.

Comment: @SimonMattes sorry, context matters, especially here

Answer (score 3):

If you, like me, want to **deploy** an ASP.NET Core MVC application

- on an internal network
- don't want *[IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)* or *WebHostService*
- don't care about Linux/Mac
- and want to hide the Kestrel console from the user

then you should read Microsoft's official documentation on how to *[host an ASP.NET Core application in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service)*.

Comment: this works well if you're looking to host static content -- however, if you want to spawn worker processes with isolated memory space. A hack for now is to Dllimport kernel32 and call FreeConsole(), or as others have mentioned use editbin.exe in your postbuild event

Comment: @SamirBanjanovic calling `FreeConsole` will not hide (release) the console window because it's owned by the runtime (dotnet), not the netcore DLL.

Comment: @McGuireV10 that is true if you run the app via dotnet command. If you're running the app as standalone after publish the `freeconsole()` works

Comment: Fair point, I had forgotten the self-contained publish option produces an exe (too much bloat for me in SCDs at this point in time).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best or cleanest solution, but a trick I've used before.  If you start a new Windows Forms application, then remove the reference to the form from the Program.cs file, it will run the application in the background with nothing showing up in the taskbar or on the desktop.  It does appear in Task Manager though.

I used this trick to write an app to play a prank on a friend.  It would run in the background and perform a system beep at random intervals.  Again, probably not the most elegant solution, but one way of doing it.

Comment: if it's a Winform application you can just do `this.Hide()` and the form isn't shown. OP wants to hide the console.

Comment: I don't think WinForms is supported on dotnet core yet

Answer (score 1):

I tried editing the `.xproj` file, but it seems it is ignored by Visual Studio/.NET.

I don't think it is currently supported as .NET was developed with web sites and console applications in mind. Microsoft has recently decided they will revert back to good old MSBuild. (*[Changes to Project.json](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/)*)

So, I think your best bet is to wait till then.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide a .net core console application on runtime as soon it starts using  windows api call. see the sample code below

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace HideConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("press any key to hide console window");
            Console.ReadKey();
            VsConsoleWindow(0);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void VsConsoleWindow(int i)
        {
           
            IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // value of cv = 0 hide console window  
                // value of cv = 1 show console window
                ShowWindow(hWnd, i);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);
            }
            return;
        }



    }
}
```

https://github.com/robinsondominic/hide-net-core-console-application

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) class. Specifically the CreateNoWindow Property.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = newProcessStartInfo("Name", "args");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

The class name and property vary a little based on the version on .NET you're using. It is also important to note that this needs to be populated and called before the process is initialized. This works when the program in question is being called programmatically or from PowerShell scripts, etc.