# Is there a way to create a console-less dotnet core application?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-core

In previous .NET frameworks it is possible to create a Windows Form application devoid of the Application.Run() method call, which effectively runs the process without a form or console window being shown.

I'm aware that there is an option to use a DLLImport for FreeConsole() however unlike the barely modified Windows Form application, it will display a console window for some fractions of a second. I am seeking to avoid displaying a console fullstop.

I'm aware that there is an option to use a service as well, although I would like to avoid doing so  if possible. The build environment I am using is Arch Linux using dotnet-core 3.0 targeting Windows using the standalone publish build argument.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a potential solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776695/is-it-possible-to-run-net-core-console-application-silently-hide-console-windo