# Publishing a wpf application with WinExe is still opening a console host window

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dotnet-publish

The publish is being done via docker.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build

// restore
...

// build
..

// publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-build -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true -r win-x64 --self-contained true -o C:/dist
```

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ApplicationIcon>Common\Images\favicon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <StartupObject>Dtail.Platform.Launcher.App.App</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

   ...

</Project>
```

**Expected behavior:**

Since the `OutputType` is set to `WinExe`, it should hide the console host ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776695/is-it-possible-to-run-a-net-core-console-application-silently-hide-console-win))

**Actual behavior:**

The application is opening along with a console window

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies force the console window open, e.g. Selenium. Check whether your dependencies have their own methods for hiding the window.