# How do I inject dependencies into a custom WebHostService in a .Net Core project?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I'm trying to create a service which will run as a Windows service as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346383/hosting-asp-net-core-as-windows-service). My problem is that the example Web Host Service constructor only takes an `IWebHost` parameter. My service needs a constructor more like this:

```
public static class HostExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsMyService(this IWebHost host)
    {
        var webHostService =
            new MyService(host, loggerFactory, myClientFactory, schedulerProvider);
        ServiceBase.Run(webHostService);
    }
}
```

My `Startup.cs` file looks similar to this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddInMemoryCollection();

    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    this.container.RegisterSingleton<IConfiguration>(this.Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
        new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(this.container);

    this.container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();

    this.InitializeContainer(app, loggerFactory);
    this.container.Verify();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
}

private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    container.Register(() => loggerFactory, Lifestyle.Singleton);
    container.Register<IMyClientFactory>(() => new MyClientFactory());
    container.Register<ISchedulerProvider>(() => new SchedulerProvider());
}
```

Obviously I'm using Simple Injector as a DI container. It's registered with the `IServiceCollection` as detailed in [their documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html).

My question is how do I access the framework's container (the IServicesCollection) in the HostExtensions class so that I can inject the necessary dependencies into `MyService`? For MVC controllers that's all just  handled under the covers, but I don't know of any documentation detailing how to access it where needed elsewhere.

Comment: I am curious, why use another DI container when the one (`IServiceCollection`) that comes with .Net Core works just fine? This seems like adding a layer that is completely unnecessary. Is there some advantage?

Comment: @R.Richards The built-in container isn't very suited for building bigger applications that are built around the SOLID principles, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682214/264697).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to make a few minor tweeks to your code to get this working.

#### 1. Make the `Container` a `public static` field in the `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static readonly Container container = new Container();
```

#### 2. Move the verification out of the `Startup` and into the `Main`:

Doing this allows extra registration to be added to the container, after the `Startup` class is done with it, but before the application is actuall started:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(directoryPath)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    // Don't forget to remove the Verify() call from within the Startup.
    Startup.Container.Verify();

    ...
}
```

#### 3. Register your `MyService` as singleton

Registering it explictly as singleton in the container allows Simple Injector to run diagnostics on it and prevents accidental captive dependencies that the `MyService` might accidentaly have. You should register it as singleton, because it will be kept alive for the duration of the application:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(directoryPath)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    Startup.Container.RegisterSingleton<MyService>();

    Startup.Container.Verify();

    ...
}
```

#### 3. Register missing dependencies that `MyService` requires.

`MyService` depends on host, loggerFactory, myClientFactory and schedulerProvider, which are not all currently registered.

The `host` can be registered inside the `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    Startup.Container.RegisterSingleton<MyService>();
    Startup.Container.RegisterSingleton<IWebHost>(host);

    Startup.Container.Verify();

    ...
}
```

While the `loggerFactory` can be registered inside the `Startup` class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    Container.RegisterSingleton(loggerFactory);

    ...
}
```

I assume that the `myClientFactory` and `schedulerProvider` dependencies are already registered in the container.

#### 4. Replace the `RunAsMyService` extension method with simple resolve from the container

Since the `MyService` is successfully registered in the container with all its dependencies, we should now be able to resolve it from the container and pass it on to the `ServiceBase.Run` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    Startup.Container.Verify();

    ServiceBase.Run(Startup.Container.GetInstance<MyService>());
}
```

That should be all.

One last note, depending on the type of application you are building, you might not need such elaborate `Startup` class at all. You might move the configuration of the container closer to the `Main` method. Whether you should do this, depends on how much you actually need.

Here's an example of working without an `Startup` class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();

    IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Configure framework components
            services.AddOptions();
        })
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            app.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);

            // Apply cross-wirings:
            container.RegisterSingleton(
                app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    container.RegisterSingleton<MyService>();
    container.RegisterSingleton(host);

    container.Verify();

    ServiceBase.Run(Startup.Container.GetInstance<MyService>());
}
```

Comment: i am facing the same issue can you please elaborate what is the container?

Comment: I'm sure you're not having the same problem, because in that case you would definitely know what the container is; this question is about Simple Injector.